# Beurling density $D(X)$ of $X=\{x_j\in\mathbb R, \ |x_j-x_{i}|>\gamma>0: \ i,j\in\mathbb Z\}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

Beurling density of set $X$ is defined (see, for example "Nonuniform Sampling and Reconstruction in Shift-Invariant Spaces" by Aldroubi and Grochenig) as:
$$D(X)=\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} \inf_{y\in\mathbb R} \frac{\#X\cap\left(y+[0,r]\right)}{r}$$
where $X=\{x_j\in\mathbb R: \ j\in\mathbb Z\}$. This is a new topic for me. I would calculate this value for the set
$$X=\{x_j\in\mathbb R, \ |x_j-x_{i}|>\gamma>0: \ i,j\in\mathbb Z\}$$
Any suggestions please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not really define $X$. Also I think that the term Banach density is more common than Beurling density, e.g. at wikipedia or mathworld.

Comment: This, in fact, was my doubt, namely what perhaps, thus defining the set, I had not given the information needed to calculate $D(X)$.

Comment: Mark: To me, the problem reads as "Determine all possible values attained by $D(X)$ when $X$ is a subset of $\bf R$ s.t. $\inf_{x,y \in X: x \ne y} |x-y| > \gamma$ (for a fixed $\gamma > 0$)." That makes perfect sense, doesn't it?. @Jan-Christoph Schlage-Puchta: $D(X)$ is a typical (though, to my eyes, very unnatural) variant of one special instance of a rather general notion of (lower) density that goes back to Arne Beurling, see e.g. p. 18 in G. Kutyniok's *Affine Density in Wavelet Analysis* and references therein. The term "(lower) Banach density" refers to another specialization of (...)

Comment: (...) Beurling's general definition, where the domain is, say, $\bf Z$ or $\bf N$, see e.g. Definition 3.7 in H. Furstenberg's *Recurrence in Ergodic Theory and Combinatorial Number Theory*. (For one thing, note that $D(X)$ can be larger than $1$, whereas it's commonly understood that a "density" is, by and large, a kind of (set) function with image in $[0,1]$.)